# Running php file with Open Source Job Scheduler

Tags: java, php, javascript, zend-framework, job-scheduling

I have a php file `test.php`. I want to run it with Open Source Job Scheduler at specified intervals. How can I do that? Should I create a xml file for it?

I read the documentation

http://www.sos-berlin.com/mediawiki/index.php/How_to_execute_a_PHP_script_with_JS

But my doubt is that how do I run a file located at certain folder instead of writing the code in xml file. Should I write include script `include "test.php";` in xml file? Can any one help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from their document it self.

Refer

http://www.sos-berlin.com/mediawiki/index.php/Creating_a_Job

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<spooler>
  <config>
    <jobs>

       <job name = "my_shell_script">
          <process file  = "my_shell_script.sh"
                   param = ""/>
          <run_time repeat = "3600"
                    begin  = "00:00"
                    end    = "24:00"/>
       </job>

     </jobs>
   </config>
</spooler>
```

The job named "my_shell_script" will be started every hour (see ) and will execute the script my_shell_script.sh (see ).

Answer (score 0):

If your php file is executable then yes. 
You can simpely do include in the php code.

Also try to google for CRON JOBS if you use linux server.